# Object refuses to save changes in Rails IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, irb, has-one

Good morning all,

I've got an association that I'm working on, and for some reason, I can't get it to save changes to the object in question when I'm debugging it in IRB.  I was wondering if anyone could point out my problem.

Here is the association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :affiliates
  has_one :managed_affiliate, :class_name => "Affiliate", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
end

class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "User"
  #The affiliates table has a foreign key field of manager_id
end
```

When I fire up the IRB, I can grab a User.first and Affiliate.first.  I can set the user's managed_affiliate just fine.  However, when I save, that is not reflected at all in the affiliate - it has no manager.  Likewise, I can set the affiliate's manager just fine (Affiliate.first.manager = User.first).  It returns like everything is ok, but when I go to save it simply returns "false."  If I activate the IRB logging function, this is the output:

```
SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
SQL (0.2ms)   ROLLBACK
```

Is there any obvious reason why this association won't save properly?

Also, here is the schema for the affiliates table:

```
create_table "affiliates", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "website"
    t.integer  "market_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "logo_file_name"
    t.string   "logo_content_type"
    t.integer  "logo_file_size"
    t.boolean  "track_subs"
    t.integer  "manager_id"
  end
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::Base#save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001844) will return false if a validation fails or if any `before_*` callbacks on the model returns false.

Comment: It must have had something to do with the validations, because when I wrote a quick form to add a manager through a browser, it works like a champ.

Thanks!